# Matrices in which product of elements in each row and each column = 1

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics

Given all a $\times$ b  matrices whose entries are equal to 1 or -1 only. In how many of these matrices the product of elements in each row and each column equal to 1?

How do I approach this? My friend gave me a hint that a $\times$ b matrices are related to a-1 $\times$ b-1 matrices. I am unable to get any kind of recursion going here.

Comment: Suppose you already know all entries but those in the last row and column - that is, you know the entries in an $(a-1) \times (b-1)$ submatrix.  Can you fill in the missing entries to have the property you desire?  If so, how many ways can you do so?  Does this number depend on the entries in the submatrix?

Comment: Okay so maybe for any given a-1 $\times$ b-1 matrix we could build  
a $\times$ b matrix with desired property. There is only way right? How do I prove this formally? I have tried only for small cases.

Comment: That's exactly right - every $(a-1) \times (b-1) $ matrix extends to a unique $a \times b $ matrix with the given property. For each new entry you have to fill in, there is either a row or column whose product needs to be fixed, which ensures there's only one possible value. The tricky part is making sure that there is exactly one value for the corner entry, since this isn't directly linked to the $(a-1) \times (b-1) $ submatrix. However, what row/column is it linked to?

Comment: There is only a unique entry for the corner entry since it now depends on the newly filled colum/row. But how can we be sure there is no conflict, since the newly added row might require a 1 whereas the column might require a -1 in order to get the desired property.

Comment: Once this conflict is resolved I think the question is done since then there are 2 choices for each of the (a-1) $ \times $ (b-1) elements

Comment: Exactly, you have to check that the newly filled row and column do not contradict each other.  Hint: what is the product of the entries in the newly filled row (without the corner) in terms of the $(a-1) \times (b-1) $ submatrix? What about the new column? They should be the same, hence there can be no conflict.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to see any relation between newly filled row(without corner) and the a-1 $\times$ b-1 matrix.

Comment: Each entry in the bottom row is the product of the $a-1$ entries in the column above it.  Hence the product of all the entries in the bottom row except the last is the product of all the entries in the $(a-1) \times (b-1)$ submatrix.  A similar argument works for the entries in the last column.  This shows that the bottom row and last column always agree, so there is a unique way to fill the corner entry without conflicts.

Comment: I was thinking like $a_i $ * (Product of a-1 entries in column above it) = 1 . Here since entries can be 1 or -1 we get $a_i$ = (Product of a-1 entries). Didn't realise that. Thanks so much. This was more helpful than a full answer.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped!